# CSS rule not being overridden

Tags: css

I ran into a weird issue, where a CSS rule doesn't seem to be applied correctly on Safari/Chrome/Firefox on Mac.

Given the following html code:

```
<table id="table" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td id="cell">
            Hello
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then the following css code works as I expected (as in the cell doesn't have padding on top):

```css
td { padding: 10px; }
#cell { padding-top: 0px; }
```

But this one doesn't:

```css
#table td { padding: 10px; }
#cell { padding-top: 0px; }
```

(Try it out online at: http://jsfiddle.net/xkduyk7m/)

I expected both versions of the CSS to yield the same effect in this case, but in the second case the rule that is added later and that applies to the specific cell doesn't override the first rule.

Why?

Comment: Check this out: http://specificity.keegan.st/

Comment: More complex rules have higher precedence

Comment: To fix this, just change your second example so `#cell { padding-top: 0px !important; }`

Comment: #table #cell or td#cell would override.

Comment: @alexpmil Never use `!important` unless you have no other way to solve a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each css selector has a value "weight". The combination makes it override one another, and when they match, the order of writing will define the precedence.

Here are W3's docs about how to calculate the precedence: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

Answer (score 2):

Css rules are not place bound. A more specific css selector will override another less specific. Place is only used in case they are both as specific.

In your case `#table td` is more specific than just `#cell` and thus is not being overridden.
If you use `#table #cell` it should work

Comment: Alright, I had a different idea about "specificity", as in id applies to just one element and is more specific than a selector that selects multiple elements.

Comment: It is more often used with classes and I guess browsers used the same rules for classes and id's. And if you replace your example with classes you can directly see that a cell is less specific than a cell in a table. It's not always the most logical explanation that wins ;) It's something you learn by trial and error and a good source inspector helps a lot too! ;)

Comment: With classes it indeed makes sense. Also the source inspector actually pointed me to the fact that the second rule was detected but not applied in favour of the first rule. If only it would tell you why yet!

Comment: That is the trial and error part.
Generally followed by a great sense of pride when you are able to resolve the issue! Even if in a lot of cases you shouldn't have made the error in the first place ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the #table td { padding:10px; } will wright out as #table td { padding-top:10px; padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-left:10px; } by the browser. And this priority over your #cell { padding-top:0px; } . try one of the fallowing 2 options

Option 1

```
#table td { padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; }
#table #cell { padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px; }
```

Option 2

```
#table td { padding: 10px; }
#table #cell { padding-top: 0px !important; }
```

Sorry for the bolding using stack overflow android app and the hash makes it bold sorry for that