# Override parent settings in child class in css

Tags: html, css

This has been bothering me for a while, tried everything, but no good solution.

In my stylesheet I have

```
.message input[type='submit'] {
    background-color: grey;
    color: #d5d5d5; 
    cursor: pointer;
    font: 13px/30px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 40px;
    min-width: 120px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.tool {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:40px 40px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    min-width: 50px;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

The .message styles all (text) submit buttons in a form to look nice, the second styles (icon) tool buttons.  So now when I have a form with both types of button, I try to set the class on the tool buttons, but the .message settings take precedence.

```
<form class="message">
    <input type="submit">OK</submit>
    <input type="submit" class="tool"/>
</form>
```

How to get the child class to override the parent settings.  I know I can use an id, but I'm trying to avoid that.

I've tried,

```
.message .tool {...}
```

but no success,

Comment: Please, check my accepted answer about CSS selectors precedence combinations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654332/css-rule-not-being-overridden/25654396#25654396

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, browsers use the most-specific rule they can find. `.message input[type='submit']` is more specific than `.tool` or even `.message .tool`. `.message input[type='submit'].tool` would be more specific than the existing rule, so that should work.